# joining of selects

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have been trying to join two selects with various variants. Using UNION left me with message "too many values", inner join was completely refusing to run because I had no joinable entities and I thought perhaps this could be the correct path.

I am trying to create a small table of three rows ("bu", "bu_plus", "bu_minus") and two columns (aggregated number from selects added to the bu names)

This is my select now

```
SELECT
(SELECT LEVEL, decode(level, 1,'bu_minus', 2,'bu_plus', 3,'bu') AS kombi
FROM dual
WHERE
1 <= (SELECT (SELECT
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM c2
    WHERE
    --conditions A
    ) FROM dual
 ) AS bu_minus FROM dual
 AND 2 <= (SELECT (SELECT
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)  
    FROM c2
    WHERE
    --conditions B
    ) FROM dual
 ) AS bu_plus FROM dual
AND 3 <= SELECT ((SELECT
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM c2
    WHERE
    --conditions A
    ) FROM dual )+
  (SELECT
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM c2
    WHERE
    --conditions B
    ) FROM dual)
 ) AS bu FROM dual) AS uc

 ) AS TYPE FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is recommended reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a really, really complicated (and possibly incorrect; you have way too many select from duals for a start!) way of doing conditional counts.

In the absence of input data and expected output, I think what you're trying to do could be more easily written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN <conditions A> THEN 1 END) bu_minus,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN <conditions B> THEN 1 END) bu_plus,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN <conditions A> THEN 1 END) + COUNT(CASE WHEN <conditions B> THEN 1 END) bu
        FROM   c2
        WHERE  <conditions A>
        OR     <conditions B>)
UNPIVOT (counts FOR bu_type IN (bu_minus, bu_plus, bu));
```

This works by first of all calculating the conditional counts in a single row and then unpivoting them into 3 rows.

It has the advantage of only selecting from the main table once and is much simpler and easier to maintain than your original query.

However, this is just a guess, and with the absence of more information from you it's impossible to say if that's what you're really trying to do.